Make xrdp use the active session (HDMI output)
I have a RPi4 booting into X11 with a certain user logged in (raspi-config) and showing output on HDMI. I've got xrdp  installed which allows to use mstsc to connect to the RPi. It starts a new session though instead of attaching to the existing one.
How can I attach to the existing session using xrdp, or another RDP package? Note I'm not looking for guidance to use VNC or other protocols.
I have a similar setup where I'm using Ubuntu (on Intel hardware) with default X11 and Settings -> Sharing -> Remote Desktop enabled, and which allows for taking over the active session/screen. This setting isn't available on the RPi though (at least not by default).
Using Debian Bookworm 64 bit.
